# cors моросит не дает нормально учитяс

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, linux-mint

перепробовал все способы ничего не нашел ОС Linux Mint Mate20 пытался добавлять mode:"no-cors" не помогло пытался менять порты не помогло ошибка в браузере hrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

вот что возвращает

Response body: (...) bodyUsed: false headers: Headers {} ok: false redirected: false status: 403 statusText: "Forbidden" type: "cors" url: "http://localhost:4000/auth/users" [[Prototype]]: Response

server

```js
export default App;

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const cors = require("cors")
const authRouter = require("./authRouter")
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());
app.use("/auth",authRouter)

const start = async () =>{
    try{
     
        app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log("server start "))
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

start()
```

client

```js
import {React,useEffect,useState} from "react"

function App() {


  const [dfds , setsdf] = useState(null)

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/auth/users")  
    .then((response)=>{
      setsdf(response)
    })
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{console.log(dfds);},[dfds])
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Ос тут вообще неважна. Настраивайте CORS.  Информации про него куча. Начните с учебника https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch-crossorigin

Comment: Отдельный вопрос зачем вообще заморачиваться кроссдоменными запросами, а не просто отдавать всё с одного домена…

Comment: да я дурачек еще просто маладой балбес учусь кароче не умею пока что